# База данных по данным на сервере

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

В общем, программа должна сканировать определенные директории и собирать информацию о файлах(Например, путь к файлам, размер и т п).

Как правильнее будет хранить пути к файлам в БД?

Вложенность заранее неизвестна, а кол-во файлов очень много.

У меня 3 идеи:

1. Сделать таблицу, которая ссылается сама на себя и каждый раз строить файловое дерево. С одной стороны, будет меньше тратится места на хранение путей, а с другой, я думаю, что каждый раз все это строить-это ресурсоемко и неоптимально.
2. Хранить список директорий в одной сущности, а файлы в другой. Файлы ссылаются на директории. На мой взгляд самый оптимальный вариант.
3. Хранить в атрибуте сущности путь к файлу целиком.

Comment: Зачем вы переизобретаете auditd?

Comment: @gbg , а он в базу писать умеет? Не нагрузит ли мне сервер, если будет огромная шара и на ней будут изменения? Мне достаточно будет раз в день снимать показатели.

Comment: специально для того, чтобы не грузить сервер, он пишет логи в своем формате. Потом их можно распарсить, если вам сильно хочется.

Comment: @gbg ну в любом случае это не отменяет вопроса:). Мне всё равно понадобится база для хранения логов.

Comment: Может быть вам подойдут файловые таблицы: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff929144(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: У меня есть подобная БД. использовал одну таблицу, практически как в вашем первом варианте. НО строить каждый раз дерево слишком затратно. Поэтому для записей обозначающих каталог в специальном поле хранится полный путь. Для обычный файлов в этом поле NULL. Алгоритм получения полного пути для любой записи одинаков: берем путь из родительской записи (она же всегда каталог) и дописываем имя данного файла.

Answer (score 1):

Т.е. вам не нужно будет обновлять данные о файлах?

Только записать раз в сутки и всё?

Тогда 2) или 3) вариант. 2), если критична память, 3) если критична скорость работы с данными. Хотя выигрыша будет не много..

1)вариант сразу нет. На строки, которые хранят путь вы может и меньше памяти потратите. А вот на внешний ключ на себя с сопутствующим индексом тоже некоторая память потратится.
Работать с такой структурой будет неудобно и не оптимально, сравнительно с вариантами 2) и 3).

**upd:** я бы покопал в сторону что-то переиспользовать для этих целей. Возможно действительно FileTable будет хорошим решением.