# Заполнение БД с большой скоростью

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado

В продолжение к этому вопросу:
[База данных по данным на сервере](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/542705/%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5)

Базу я развернул и программу написал. Я сравнивал скорость работы программы без вставки в БД и со вставкой бд и заметил, что в первом случае программа завершается быстрее, чем во втором случае.

Вставку осуществляю по 1 записи. Можно ли заполнять БД с более высокой скоростью?

Например, вот так выглядит класс, который добавляет файлы:

```
public class FileProvider:BaseProvider
{
    public static int Insert(int folder_id, FileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            return conn.ExecuteScalar<int>(@"INSERT INTO dbo.[File](Folder_id,FileName,FileSizeMB) VALUES (@Folder_id,@FileName,@FileSizeMB)
                                    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", new { Folder_id = folder_id, FileName= fileInfo.Name, FileSizeMB = fileInfo.Length/1048576.0});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `conn.Open()` выполнить заранее.  вынести на вверх   `new SqlConnection(ConnStr)` и это существенно сократит время

Comment: @SeniorAutomator Тогда, наверное, соединение еще придется ручками закрывать?

Comment: Передавайте в метод сразу массив того что нужно вставить. Сейчас у вас открывается соединение на каждый вызов, это долго.

Comment: @nzeemin, я думаю, что в таком случае проще из вне передавать открытое соединение.

Answer (score 5):

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/490269/193999) про быструю загрузку. Если сможете подать `IDataReader` на вход `SqlBulkCopy` - ещё лучше. Но в данном случае потребуется небольшая модификация, поскольку возвращается `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.

В связи с этим можно создать временную таблицу (напр. `#Files`), с помощью `SqlBulkCopy` в неё делаете вставку. Потом из неё делаете вставку в основную таблицу. Вставленные id (вместе с FileName, если важно их сопоставить) направляете в `OUTPUT`

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[File](Folder_id,FileName,FileSizeMB)
OUTPUT INSERTED.id--, INSERTED.FileName
SELECT Folder_id,FileName,FileSizeMB
FROM #Files
```

Эту команду выполняете, результат (список `id` или пары `id, FileName`) вычитываете с помощью `SqlDataReader` или с помощью `SqlDataAdapter`.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае возможно сделать метод `InsertRange()`, который принимает на входе `IEnumerable <T>`, где `T` - класс с полями `int folder_id, FileInfo fileInfo`. Далее  смотри здесь:
1) https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3184/insert-multiple-rows-into-a-sql-table - пишем в таблицу в памяти затем в БД
2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913371/sqlbulkcopy-from-a-list - используем готовую реализацию п.1.